# Why python first prints out the class method?

Tags: python, class, methods

I have written a sample code like below. I wonder why the method prints out first even it is on lower lines...

```
class Dog():
    species = "Mammals"
    legs = 4
    def __init__ (self,breed, name, spots, height):
        self.breed = breed
        self.name = name
        self.spots = spots
        self.height = height

    def bark(self,number):
        for i in range(number):
            print("My name is {}".format(self.name))

MyDog = Dog(breed = "Huskie", name = "MyDog", spots = True, height = "Tall")

print(MyDog.species,MyDog.legs,MyDog.breed,MyDog.name,MyDog.spots,MyDog.bark(3),MyDog.height,sep="\n")
```

Comment: dont understand the question. What do you expect the code should do and what does the code do in reality?

Comment: `bark` prints some output. That's being called from the print statement at the bottom of your code. So you're calling print on an object that prints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`print` is just a function like any other, and Python evaluates all arguments to a function before calling that function. Otherwise the function wouldn't know the values of its arguments and wouldn't know what to do. So `MyDog.bark(3)` must be evaluated before it's possible to call `print(..., MyDog.bark(3), ...)`.

Comment: Note that there really isn't in point in printing `MyDog.bark()`, as that method doesn't return anything.

Comment: Ok. bark method must be evaluated first kind of response it reasonable, thansk for the answer. What would you recommend to change my code so that i could see bark method printing in its own order?

Comment: @ÖzgürEkinci Call bark after printing the rest.